# c pointer to struct issue

Tags: c, pointers, struct

The following code is giving me an error at the arrow in the second to last statement. I have no idea why this is . Could someone please tell me why?

I have no idea where to even begin. I thought it is correct but there is some issue.

```
      /* 
 * File:   newmain.c
 * Author: user1
 *
 * Created on May 26, 2015, 4:30 PM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
/*
 * 
 */


#ifndef KEYTYPE
#define KEYTYPE      char *
#endif

#ifndef VALUETYPE
#define VALUETYPE     double
#endif

#ifndef TYPE
#define TYPE struct association
//# define TYPE int
#endif

struct association
{

    KEYTYPE key;
    VALUETYPE value;

};

struct DynArr
{
    TYPE *data;     /* pointer to the data array */
        //struct association *data;
    int size;       /* Number of elements in the array */
    int capacity;   /* capacity ofthe array */
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    struct DynArr *da;
    da = malloc(sizeof(struct DynArr));


    assert(da!= 0);
    da->capacity = 2;
    da->data = malloc(sizeof(TYPE) * da->capacity);
    assert(da->data != 0);
    da->size = 0;


    if(da->data[0]->key == 2) //test.c:58:10: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct DynArr’)    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Is the `typedef`-button on your keyboard broken?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong operator, your instance of `struct DynArr` is not a pointer, hence you must use the `.` operator.

```
struct DynArr da;
/* This is also wrong because `capacity' has not been initialized yet! */
assert(da.capacity > 0); 
      /* ^ it's not a poitner */
```

and in all the other cases the same.

When the instance is a poitner of struct, like

```
struct DynArr  da;
struct DynArr *pda;

pda = &da;
pda->capacity = 0;
 /* ^ it's correct here */
```

**EDIT**:

After you edited your question I can see the problem

```
if(da->data[0]->key == 2)
```

`da->data` is of type `TYPE *` and you are dereferencing a pointer to it's first element in `da->data[0]`, so it's no longer of type `TYPE *` i.e. not a pointer, so you need

```
if(da->data[0].key == 2)
```

Comment: It gives the same error with a pointer. I made a simplied example to see if i could post it here but in the original problem it is using a pointer. Ive modified the code to use a pointer and it still gives the same thing.

Comment: You should never post *simplified* sample of the code unless it **reproduces the problem** I am sorry for being rude, I will delete that comment now.