# c pointers to struct issue

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Would someone please help me with thhis c pointers issue. It seems to me like it should work but there must be something im not understanding as the code doesnt compile. On the line where is says this: ERROR<<<<>>>>>>>>. I think the problem is with function getDynArr which is at the tag:  GETDYNARR<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>. I think getDynArr(da, i) may be returning int for some reason?

```
    /*  dynArr.c: Dynamic Array implementation. */
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef KEYTYPE
#define KEYTYPE      char *
#endif

#ifndef VALUETYPE
#define VALUETYPE     double
#endif

#ifndef TYPE
#define TYPE struct association
//# define TYPE int
#endif

struct association
{

    KEYTYPE key;
    VALUETYPE value;

};

struct DynArr
{
    TYPE *data;     /* pointer to the data array */
   // struct association *data;
    int size;       /* Number of elements in the array */
    int capacity;   /* capacity ofthe array */
};

///////////////////dictionary Section



void dyArrayDictionaryPut(struct DynArr *vec, KEYTYPE key, VALUETYPE val)
{

    struct association *ap;
    if (dyArrayDictionaryContainsKey(vec,key))
        dyArrayDictionaryRemove(vec, key);
    ap = malloc(sizeof(struct association));
    assert(ap != 0);
    ap->key = key;
    ap->value = val;
    //dyArrayAdd(vec, ap);
    addDynArr(vec, ap);
}

VALUETYPE dyArrayDictionaryGet(struct DynArr *da, KEYTYPE key, VALUETYPE *valptr)
{
    struct association *ap;
    int i = 0;
    if(dyArrayDictionaryContainsKey(da, key))
    {
        for ( i = 0; i <  da->size; i++)
        {
            //if(da->data[i]->key == key)
            if(da->data[i].key == key)
            {
                //return da->data->value;


                struct association temp3;

                temp3 = getDynArr(da, i); //ERROR<<<<<ERROR>>>>>>>>>incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct association' from type 'int'

                //ap = getDynArr(da, i);

                //*valptr = ap->value;
            }
        }        
    }

}

int dyArrayDictionaryContainsKey(struct DynArr *da, KEYTYPE key)
{

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < da->size; i++)
    {

        if(da->data[i].key == key)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

void dyArrayDictionaryRemove(struct DynArr *da, KEYTYPE key)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < da->size; i++)
    {
        if(da->data[i].key == key)
        {
            removeAtDynArr(da, i);
            return;
        }
    }



}
////



void _initDynArr(struct DynArr *v, int capacity)
{
    assert(capacity > 0);
    assert(v!= 0);
    v->data = malloc(sizeof(TYPE) * capacity);
    assert(v->data != 0);
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = capacity;

}

struct DynArr* createDynArr(int cap)
{
    struct DynArr *r;
    assert(cap > 0);
    r = malloc(sizeof( struct DynArr));
    assert(r != 0);
    _initDynArr(r,cap);
    return r;
}

void freeDynArr(struct DynArr *v)
{
    assert(v!=0);

    if(v->data != 0)
    {
        free(v->data);  /* free the space on the heap */
        v->data = 0;    /* make it point to null */
    }
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = 0;
}

void deleteDynArr(struct DynArr *v)
{
    assert (v!= 0);
    freeDynArr(v);
    free(v);
}

void _dynArrSetCapacity(struct DynArr *v, int newCap)
{
    int i;
    TYPE *oldData;
    int oldSize = v->size;
    oldData = v->data;

    printf("========Resizing========\n");
    /* Create a new dyn array with larger underlying array */
    _initDynArr(v, newCap);

    for(i = 0; i < oldSize; i++){
        v->data[i] = oldData[i];
    }

    v->size = oldSize;
    /* Remember, init did not free the original data */
    free(oldData);

#ifdef ALTERNATIVE
    int i;

    /* Create a new underlying array*/
    TYPE *newData = (TYPE*)malloc(sizeof(TYPE)*newCap);
    assert(newData != 0);

    /* copy elements to it */

    for(i = 0; i < v->size; i++)
    {
        newData[i] = v->data[i];
    }

    /* Delete the oldunderlying array*/
    free(v->data);
    /* update capacity and size and data*/
    v->data = newData;
    v->capacity = newCap;
#endif
}

int sizeDynArr(struct DynArr *v)
{
    assert(v!=0);
    return v->size;
}

void addDynArr(struct DynArr *v, TYPE val)
{

    assert(v!=0);

    /* Check to see if a resize is necessary */
    if(v->size >= v->capacity)
        _dynArrSetCapacity(v, 2 * v->capacity);

    v->data[v->size] = val;
    v->size++;

}

//GETDYNARR<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<GETDYNARR>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
//type is struct association
//TYPE  getDynArr(struct DynArr *v, int pos )
struct association getDynArr(struct DynArr *v, int pos)
{
    assert(v!=0);
    assert(pos < v->size);
    assert(pos >= 0);


        struct association returned = v->data[pos];


    return returned;

}



void putDynArr(struct DynArr *v, int pos, TYPE val)
{
    assert(v!=0);
    assert(pos < v->size);
    assert(pos >= 0);
    v->data[pos] = val;
}

void swapDynArr(struct DynArr *v, int i, int  j)
{
    TYPE  temp;
    assert(v!=0);
    assert(i < v->size);
    assert(j < v->size);
    assert(i >= 0);
    assert(j >= 0);

    temp = v->data[i];
    v->data[i] = v->data[j];
    v->data[j] = temp;

}

void removeAtDynArr(struct DynArr *v, int idx){
    int i;
    assert(v!= 0);
    assert(idx < v->size);
    assert(idx >= 0);

   //Move all elements up

   for(i = idx; i < v->size-1; i++){
      v->data[i] = v->data[i+1];
   }

   v->size--;

}




int main()
{



//    struct DynArr *dictionary = createDynArr(2);

  //  dyArrayDictionaryPut(dictionary, "key1", 2);

    //double result = dyArrayDictionaryGet(dictionary, "key1");

    //dyArrayDictionaryContainsKey(struct DynArr *da, KEYTYPE key)

    //dyArrayDictionaryRemove(struct DynArr *da, KEYTYPE key)



    //printf("%f\n",result);
}
```

Comment: Whhoooaaa... that's a lot of code for me to read and go through to find something that *may be returning int for some reason?*.  If you try isolating the problematic code I can try helping you.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? And the typedef-button on your keyboard is still broken?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c pointer to struct issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470868/c-pointer-to-struct-issue)

Comment: olaf i dont know how to use typedef.

Comment: THat is no excuse for posting the same question twice within 2 hours. It is not even an excuse not to use it: it is one of the first things to learn. Read a book, take a course. Using `#define' this way is plain wrong!

Answer (score 0):

`getDynArr` is not declared before it is used, the declaration is further down in the file. The compiler should warn you about that.

Since the `getDynArr` is undeclared, the compiler doesn't know what parameters it takes or what it returns. The compiler then assumes some defaults, like a return type `int`, which leads to the error you're seeing.

To fix the problem, declare the function before you try to use it.

Comment: Oh god you're correct I had no clue c was this particular about the order of declarations. I had no clue it just made up values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not going to discuss the implementation as you haven't asked for it.
In order to compile you'll need to fix the following:**

1. Missing function declarations for: getDynArr, dyArrayDictionaryRemove, dyArrayDictionaryContainsKey, addDynArr, removeAtDynArr; So you need to add the function signature just below the struct declarations, like:

   ```
   struct association
   {
       KEYTYPE key;
       VALUETYPE value;
   };

   struct DynArr
   {
        TYPE *data;     /* pointer to the data array */
        // struct association *data;
        int size;       /* Number of elements in the array */
        int capacity;   /* capacity ofthe array */
   };

   ///////////////////dictionary Section

   struct association getDynArr(struct DynArr *v, int pos);
   void dyArrayDictionaryRemove(struct DynArr *da, KEYTYPE key);
   int dyArrayDictionaryContainsKey(struct DynArr *da, KEYTYPE key);
   void addDynArr(struct DynArr *v, TYPE val);
   void removeAtDynArr(struct DynArr *v, int idx);

   ...
   ```
2. inside the function dyArrayDictionaryPut you need to call addDynArr passing the struct by value according to the function signature, so the call at line 54 would be:

   ```
   addDynArr(vec, *ap);
   ```
3. You need to compile it as c99 code, otherwise you need to remove the variable initialization on every for loop (the gcc option is -std=c99 for instance);

**Then let me give you a couple of suggestions you may find useful:**

1. You may want to consider using typedef instead of define to create an alias for the struct association;

   ```
   typedef struct
   {
       KEYTYPE key;
       VALUETYPE value;
   } association;
   ```

Then at this point you can use "association" as a type without the needs to mention it is a struct anymore (I guess you can find a better name for it as well);

2. Depending on the performance requirements, you may need to avoid returning or passing the struct by value around, using a pointer is much faster.